# View liked posts by friends's friends

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-like

If my friend likes a post on my timeline (the privacy of this post is to "Friends only"), who can see the like or the status on his/their news feed?

Answer (score 1):

Only friends in common can see the like activity.

If it was Friends of Friends, then this would change.

See: [Types of audiences](https://www.facebook.com/help/211513702214269)